# WooCommerce Pagination with Custom Loop

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, woocommerce

I have a simple page template called `Memberships`.

I want to have a simple list of WooCommerce Products with 50 items per page.
On the buttom I need a pagination element that helps me to move to the next 50 elements.

This is the page Template code

```
<?php
/**
  * Template Name: Memberships
  */

if (!defined('ABSPATH')) exit; // Exit if accessed directly


/**
 *
 * <head>
 *
 */
get_template_part('partials/head', 'page');


/**
 *
 * Header
 *
 */
get_template_part('partials/header', 'page');


/**
 *
 * Content
 *
 */
?>

<div class="row">
        <div class="category-visual focuspoint" data-focus-x="0.59" data-focus-y="0.65" data-focus-w="720"
             data-focus-h="300">

            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'full'); ?>

            <div class="category-visual-text">
                <h1 class="headline"><?php echo the_title(); ?></h1>
                <span class="subheader"><?php echo get_post(759)->post_content; ?></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php if(wc_memberships_is_user_active_member(get_current_user_id(), 'packagecloud-membership')) {?>
        <ul class="products">
            <?php
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'posts_per_page' => 5,
                'tax_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => 'packages'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => 'demo-packages'
                    )
                )
            );
            $loop = new WP_Query($args);
            if ($loop->have_posts()) {
                while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
                    /*wc_get_template_part('content', 'product');*/
                    ?>
                    <ul>
                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                    </ul>

                    <?php
                endwhile;
            } else {
                echo __('No products found');
            }
            wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>
        </ul>
        <?php } else {
            echo get_current_user_id();
        } ?>

    </div>
</div>

<?php
/**
 *
 * Footer
 *
 */
get_template_part('partials/footer', 'page');


/**
 *
 * Foot
 *
 */
get_template_part('partials/foot', 'page'); ?>
```

and this is the [output](https://db.tt/ip8896H0).

---

I tried a lot of things to get a pagination in it, nothing worked. It just doesn't show me the pagination elements or don't move me to the next elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    /**
     * Template Name: Memberships
     */

    if (!defined('ABSPATH')) exit; // Exit if accessed directly


    /**
     *
     * <head>
     *
     */
    get_template_part('partials/head', 'page');


    /**
     *
     * Header
     *
     */
    get_template_part('partials/header', 'page');


    /**
     *
     * Content
     *
     */
    ?>

    <div class="row">
            <div class="category-visual focuspoint" data-focus-x="0.59" data-focus-y="0.65" data-focus-w="720"
                 data-focus-h="300">
                <div class="category-visual-text">
                    <h1 class="headline packagecloud"><?php echo the_title(); ?></h1>
                    <span class="subheader packagecloud"><?php echo get_post(759)->post_content; ?></span>
                </div>
                <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'full'); ?>
            </div>

            <?php if(wc_memberships_is_user_active_member(get_current_user_id(), 'packagecloud-membership')) {?>
            <div class="packagecloud-wrapper">
                <ul class="products">
                    <?php
                    $args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'product',
                        'posts_per_page' => 50,
                        'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
                        'orderby' => 'title',
                        'order' => 'ASC',
                        'tax_query' => array(
                            'relation' => 'OR',
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                                'field' => 'slug',
                                'terms' => 'packages'
                            ),
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                                'field' => 'slug',
                                'terms' => 'demo-packages'
                            )
                        )
                    );
                    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
                    do_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop');

                    if ($loop->have_posts()) {
                        while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
                            ?>
                            <ul>
                                <?php the_title(); ?>
                            </ul>

                            <?php
                        endwhile;

                    } else {
                        echo __('No products found');
                    }
                    wp_reset_query();
                    wp_reset_postdata();

                    mx42_pagination($loop); ?>


                </ul>
            </div>

            <?php } else {
                echo the_excerpt();
            } ?>

        </div>
    </div>

    <?php
    /**
     *
     * Footer
     *
     */
    get_template_part('partials/footer', 'page');


    /**
     *
     * Foot
     *
     */
    get_template_part('partials/foot', 'page');
```